# Knowing what you should be using in WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

When a new package is downloaded from NuGet, how is someone supposed to know what to enter in for `@using ...`?

For example I'm trying to use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)
I downloaded it to the project off NuGet, now I'm trying to run `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);` and it says error:

`The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context`

I found it online looking up the error, so I know it's `using Newtonsoft.Json;`, but how is one supposed to know this for in the future?

Comment: Check your project/solution references.

Comment: In WebMatrix (not Vs)?

Comment: Good point. I was referring to VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the `Resolve` option from the Visual Studio context menu for namespace resolution

[image]

Comment: In WebMatrix (not Vs)?

Comment: @ZeeTee ah ok missed that, so the same option isn't available in WebMatrix?

Comment: @ZeeTee given you've accepted this answer I presume the option *does* exist?

Comment: You had the only answer so I accepted it. There is no `Resolve` in WebMatrix, and no place to see this info.

Comment: @ZeeTee then you shouldn't mark this as the accepted answer. You need to think about future visitors with the same problem, did you manage to get around the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the WebMatrix, when you open a new project, inside the root folder, there is a folder called `/bin/` where all of your dll files and these type of files that you add from the NuGet package are saved. ASP.NET saves its files there, and each time you add a new package it is saved in this location and each namespace is called from the bin folder.

You can look for each of the library file added to your web application by opening the bin folder and then looking into it. You can easily find out, what name of the file you might be looking for, for example

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

*Newtonsoft.Json.dll* is the file's name this time inside the bin folder. Next time a similar name would be there, you can look for them and then call their name.

You should know that this is the place where you call the Namespaces to be resolved in your project. As James has already provided a solution for Visual Studio, WebMatrix thing I have told you. There is no method that would automatically write the package's location. You will have to call it yourself. To find out the list of the items that you can include, you can find them inside the bin folder of your root folder.

Comment: I did notice the bin dir, and the file names inside, but what are the odds that the .dll file uses a different namespace?  Really not much you can do then huh?

Comment: Actually they are the entire project, you can just call them by their first name. The remaining would be used automatically. For example, if you include `Newtonsoft`, you can call the methods that you want, but with the prefix of `Json`

Comment: This method will only work where there is a correlation between the name of the dll and the namespace you need. Libraries can contain multiple namespaces, and often do.